# maximize an Illithid's lunch

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dungeons-and-dragons

An Illithid Savant will gain skills, class abilities and feats and either an extraordinary special attack or special quality of creatures whose brain it eats.

Assuming I get one of each of these for my character;  who is the best brain to eat to gain the most amount of Charisma?

I would guess a WarChief - to gain the class ability of + 6 Charisma.

Can anyone think of a way to get +8 or +10 or more through eating one single brain?

Leaving out spells and templates...assume I have no templates and can get most likely get access to a spell if it is good enough for me to really want it.

Comment: In before, "Pun-pun! Eat Pun-pun's brain!"

Comment: I've closed this as too broad - this question is effectively "which is the best arbitrary character to exploit, under arbitrary measurements of 'best' and arbitrary constraints", which is not reasonable for us to handle. That is not too far from "what is the best arbitrary character". This kind of discussion starter may work better [asked on a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).